# Non-nullable instance field 'httpRequestService' must be initialized

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I have the following code:

```dart
class UserService {

  HttpRequestService httpRequestService;

  // I got an error here: Non-nullable instance field 'httpRequestService' must be initialized.
  UserService({HttpRequestService? httpRequestService}) {
    this.httpRequestService = httpRequestService ?? initHttpRequestService();
  }
  
  initHttpRequestService() {
    return HttpRequestService();
  }

}
```

As you can see, an error occurred in the constructor. But the weird thing is, I've initialized the `httpRequestService` in the constructor. So why did I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`httpRequestService` assigned inside constructor body inside `{ ...}`

One way of avoiding this error is

```dart
  UserService({required HttpRequestService httpRequestService})
      : httpRequestService = httpRequestService;
```

But in your case, one is coming from an instance  method. With above pattern late won't suppress the error in this case.

Static method will do the job while it belongs to the class rather than an instance of the class

```dart
class UserService {
    HttpRequestService httpRequestService;

  UserService({HttpRequestService? httpRequestService})
      : httpRequestService = httpRequestService ?? initHttpRequestService();

  static initHttpRequestService() {
    return HttpRequestService();
  }
}
```

Also, we can use  `late`

```dart
class UserService {
  late HttpRequestService httpRequestService;

  UserService({HttpRequestService? httpRequestService}) {
    httpRequestService = httpRequestService ?? initHttpRequestService();
  }

  initHttpRequestService() {
    return HttpRequestService();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add late keyword before httpRequestService declaration

```
  late HttpRequestService httpRequestService;
```

or just make your variable nullable like this

```
 HttpRequestService? httpRequestService;
```